# Sorting array of point objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jquery-ui-sortable

Hi I want to sort an array of point objects in javascript so that the array,

`[{x: 220, y: 1080}, {x: 1, y: 0}, {x: 0, y: 1080}]`

becomes

`[{x: 0, y: 1080}, {x: 1, y: 0}, {x: 220, y: 1080}]`

Thanks in advance

Comment: `points.sort(function(a,b) { return a.x-b.x || a.y-b.y })`

Answer (score 7):

```
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    if( a.x == b.x) return a.y-b.y;
    return a.x-b.x;
});
```

This is basic functionality of `sort`...

Comment: Please use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: Why? What difference does it make here?

Comment: I've never found a single case where `===` is better to use than `==`, to be honest, in over 12 years of JS...

Comment: @YS: for that to make any difference, we'd have to imagine a scenario where `x` can be of different data types, which is entirely out of scope for the question, but even granted that, I think if one `x` were to come up as a string value, but equal to a numerical value, I'd be inclined to say we'd *want* the sort to treat them as equal.

Comment: ... and if you're concerned that `a.x` might sometimes be a string or something, you'd have a bigger problem with `a.x-b.x` than with worrying about making your sort stable.

Answer (score 2):

```
var sorted = unsorted.sort(function(a,b) { return a.x - b.x })
```

Comment: and what sort order if the x coordinates are the same?

Comment: @Alnitak. though you're right, wasn't requested in the question. +1

Comment: @Alnitak: yeah, it's true my answer doesn't deal with that.